# Internal server error Login failed for user 'DOMAIN\MACHINENAME$'

Tags: sql-server, angular, .net-core

I am stuck and can't figure this one out.

I am using VS2017 to deploy a Angular 6 application with a Dot Net Core 2 back end that talks to a SQL Server DB on a remote server.  I am not using and ORM or EF system, just straight ADO connections.

I am getting this error =

```
error: "Internal server errorLogin failed for user 'DOMAIN\MACHINENAME$'."
500 Internal Server Error
```

I have tried the following things:

- making Sure the connection string does not have Integrated Security = true
- making sure App Pool is set to No Managed Code
- that the app is not set up to use NETWORK SERVICE or LocalSystem as login

This all seemed to start in the past 2 weeks.   Before then, while the app was more simple, it was still connecting to DB just fine.  So I am not sure what would cause this error.

I do not get this error when using the site locally on my dev machine (loccalhost).  Everything connects and gets data just fine there.

*This is only when I deploy to our servers...*

Ideas?

EDIT FOR QUESTIONS

```
Connection string = data source=<IPADDRESS>;initial catalog=<DBNAME>;user id=<DBUSERNAME>;password=<DBPW>;Trusted_Connection=True;
```

Comment: Did you change your appsettings.json file for Development and Production. Make sure your connection strings have User Id and Password.

Comment: Is the error definitely coming from the code that connects to the database?  What account is the application running under?  Is there anywhere where a different account or impersonation is used?  When you say it works on your dev machine, does that have the same configuration as the machine on which it's failing, or are there other differences between the two instances?

Comment: @Amel : I did  ng build --configuration=dev   and that appeared to have made the correct config file

I also have a very simple connection string = (see above main post edit)

Comment: @JohnLBevan:  The error is raised when I click a button that makes an API call to get data from DB.
Http failure response for http:/mysite/api/mymethod: 500 Internal Server Error

Account the application is running under is Windows Authentication

No other accounts are used other than the connection string for DB user 

My local dev machine and the remote sever have the same connection to DB and use the same connection string (though locally its iis express, while server is full iis)

Comment: You have `Trusted_Connection=True;` in your connection string; remove it, since you are trying to use a username and password rather than Windows authentication.

Comment: I would emphasize Richardissimo response.  What is happening is somehow It is using the local machine account.  Most likely because you are accessing via IpAddress or DirectPc Name (like \\MyServer  ) instead of "\\someServer\SqlInstance")   Try to not use the IP Address - at least for debugging.  This can work   nnn.nnn.nnn.nnn,1433  sometimes.  You Do Not Specify a Network Library in your string.

Comment: @Richardissimo:  You were correct!  You can post that as the answer to the issue if you like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `Trusted_Connection=True;` in your connection string; remove it, since you are trying to use a username and password rather than Windows authentication.